# How to cover onIdle callback function with test react-idle-timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I use `react-idle-timer 4.6.4`

I have a component with `useIdleTimer` hook.

```
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import {logoutRequest} from "auth/actions";

const App = () => {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 const logout = () => dispatch(logoutRequest);

 useIdleTimer({
  timeout: 1000 * 60 * 5,
  onIdle: logout,
  debounce: 500
 });

 return <Component />
}
```

Also, I have a test that looks like this

```
test("render App", () => {
 render(<App />);
 const someElement = screen.getByText("Some element");
 expect(someElement).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

This test covers all lines of code except for the logout function.

How to cover the `logout` function with tests?

Comment: Where does the `dispatch` and `logoutRequest` come from?

Comment: @slideshowp2 Question have been updated. I already covered ```logoutRequest``` action separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jest.useFakeTimers() like this

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
});

test('calls logout', async () => {
  render(<App />);
  const start = Date.now();

  act(() => {
    jest.setSystemTime(start + (60 * 1000 * 5));
    fireEvent.focus(document);
  });
  
  expect(logout).toHaveBeenCalled()
});
```

taken from their tests https://github.com/SupremeTechnopriest/react-idle-timer/blob/master/tests/useIdleTimer.test.ts